# memcpy issue in ARMcc

Tags: arm

I am facing an issue of bytes being copied in a reverse order when I compile code using ARMCC.
For example :

short int dest;
short int src = 0x0010;
memcpy(&dest,&src,sizeof(short int));

The value in the dest when i look into the memory display is shown as 10 00. I wonder why doesnt it place the values in appropriate bytes in the destination. To over come this, I have to use an array and copy value byte by byte.

Is there a solution to this issue ? or it is some problem in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your arm in little endian mode, which means it stores the less significant byte at the lower address, and "reads backwards" to human perception in a bytewise memory dump.

Look at a memory dump of the original value and you will see it is the same way.

There is actually no problem (unless at some point you are communicating with a big-endian system or via a protocol that uses that standard, in which case you have to byte-swap).

Answer (score 1):

Most ARM processors (v3 and later) are actually [bi-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bi-endian_hardware). You can feed the `-bigend` option to ARMCC to compile in big endian so that the LSB will be placed at the higher memory address.

Read the [`man`](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1998/CompDesn/fromlecturer/htmlman/armcc.html) for more details.

Make sure the particular processor you are using supports this feature. You may need to change some other configuration option to get this to work properly.